# Using jQuery to prevent submit if field is empty and it return value zero even input contain data

Tags: jquery, html

When I used jQuery to check that ship city not empty it work done if it empty and prevent submit but it also prevent submit when I fill in input as it always read value=0 even it contain data.

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <div class="shipcountry">
                        <b> Select Country </b><?php
                        echo "<select required  name='shipcountry'  id='shipcountry' onchange='showCityship(this);'>";


                        if(isset($row['ship_country'])) {
                            echo " <option value='{$row["ship_country"]}' >";


                            echo $row["ship_country"];

                            "</option>";
                        } else {
                            echo "<option  value=''>Select</option>";}
                        $query = 'SELECT * FROM `country_dhl` ';
                        $res_qu = mysql_query($query);

                        while ($country = mysql_fetch_array($res_qu)) {


                            echo " <option value='{$country["country"]}'>";
                            echo $country["country"];


                            echo "</option>";
                        }
                        echo "</select>";
                        ?>
                    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-6" style="display: none;" id="othershipcountry">
 <b> City </b>
 <input type="text" name="shipcity" class="form-control"
        placeholder="Enter Your City"/>
   </div>

<div class="form-group col-md-6" style="display: none;" id="city_ship">
 <input type="text" name="shipcity" class="form-control"
        placeholder="Enter Your City"/>
   </div>
```

jquery to show and hide div

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#othershipcountry').show();
    $('#city_ship').hide();
    $('#othershipcity').hide();

    $('.shipcountry').click(function () {
        var selected = $(this).val();
        if(selected == 'Roma') {
            $('#othershipcountry').hide();
            $('#city_ship').show();
            $('#othershipcity').hide();
        } else {
            $('#othershipcountry').show();
            $('#city_ship').hide();

            $('#othershipcity').hide();
        }
    });
});



jquery  when submit

$(document).ready(function() {


    $('#submit').click(function(e) {

       if ($('#city_ship').css('display') != 'none') {

            var ship =  $('#city_ship').val();
            if (ship.length === 0) {
                console.log("city");
                alert("You must choose your Ship city ");
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }
        if ($('#othershipcountry').css('display') == 'block') {
            var ship = $('#othershipcity').val();
            if (ship.length === 0) {
                console.log("othercity");
                alert("You must fill Ship city");

                e.preventDefault();
            }
            else{
                console.log("other");
            }
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Rather than JQuery, you cqn qdd the `required` attribute to the field liek so: ` <input type="text" name="shipcity" class="form-control"
        placeholder="Enter Your City" required/>`

Comment: i can't use require as it didn't work properly with safari

Answer (score 0):

You could apply a change event to your input field, check the length of the input every time it gets changes and if it's length equals 0, so theres no input, you disable the submit button, otherwise you enable it:

```
$("#city_ship").bind("change paste keyup", function() {
{
    if (this.value.length == 0)
        $('#submit').attr("disabled", true);
    else
        $('#submit').attr("disabled", false);
});
```

Comment: it isn't work can find another solutions as main problem is also it read value zero even it contain content @Tom Doodler

Answer (score 0):

I can solve problem as the div length always return zero even it contain data, because in jQuery I try to get length of div not length of input.

Solution:

```
     <input type="text" name="shipcity" class="form-control"
        placeholder="Enter Your City"/>
```

is selected with:

```
$('[ name = "shipcity"]')
```

city_ship is just a div.